# How to preset the choice for "A new version of /boot/grub/menu.lst is available"

Tags: debian, ubuntu, apt, dpkg

I added *biosdevname=1* and a few other settings to my */etc/default/grub* on Ubuntu 16.04. Everytime there is a kernel update, I get asked this:

```
Found kernel: /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-136-generic
Found kernel: /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-135-generic
A new version of /boot/grub/menu.lst is available, but the version installed currently has
been locally modified.

  1. install the package maintainer's version
  2. keep the local version currently installed
  3. show the differences between the versions
  4. show a side-by-side difference between the versions
  5. show a 3-way difference between available versions
  6. do a 3-way merge between available versions (experimental)
  7. start a new shell to examine the situation

What would you like to do about menu.lst? 2
```

I've got like 60 machines to update and this blows up my *ansible* playbook and I have to go into each machine by hand and select "2" to keep my existing grub defaults.

I know there are dpkg environment variables to tell apt to "always overwrite" or "always keep" but I don't know of a way to tell it the choice for an individual package.

How can I tell *apt* to "always keep" my */etc/default/grub* configuration?

Comment: Please note that you are using GRUB 1.x version (nowadays called *Legacy GRUB*). Don't you want to upgrade?

Comment: Probably due to many years of `do-release-upgrade`. I have no idea.

Answer (score 2):

The program that provides this question is called `dpkg`. It is called by `apt` in latter phase of package installation on Debian-like systems. You can pass configuration options to it using `-o Dpkg::Options::="OPTIONS"`. And because you want to execute `dpkg` with `--force-confold` (force configuration – old), use this:

```
apt-get install -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confold" …
```

This will disable **all** modifications of configuration files. you can combine it with `--force-confdef` to update configuration that was not modified by you:

```
apt-get install -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confdef" -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confold" …
```

See also: [Automatically keep current version of config files when apt-get install](https://serverfault.com/a/259238)

Comment: Thank you for this but is there a way to set the option for only a certain package (like `grub`)? something like `apt-get  upgrade -s  -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confdef" -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confold"  grub-pc`

Answer (score 0):

The answer @jiwopene gave is fine but it applies to *every package* upgraded on the system. This is not what I asked about because some upgraded software will not function when old, deprecated options exist in the config file. Other packages will simply fill log files with warning messages (`sshd`, `postfix` for instance) which can cause needless overhead for central logging (database indices, storage, search performance, etc). I ended up using the script below. It applies the options mentioned by @jiwopene but specifies to upgrade only the *linux-generic* package. It then applies `autoremove` with the same options to remove old kernels.

The `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive` environment variable was needed because some systems presented a text-mode dialog box (assuming this is from the `dialog` package being installed) to ask about overwriting the installed config files and seemingly ignored the `dpkg` options specified.

```
#!/bin/bash
# disable any dialog prompts
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

# check if linux-generic package is installed here
dpkg -l linux-generic &>/dev/null

# if so, upgrade linux-generic package only and force-keep any config files
if [ "$?" -eq 0 ]; then
   apt-get install -y --only-upgrade -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confdef" -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confold" linux-generic

   # next, autoremove the old kernels and again force-keep grub config
   apt-get -y autoremove -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confdef" -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confold"
fi
```